# Maintaining relative location of objects across different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, html5

I'm developing a very simple interactive HTML5 game, in which I need to show a room having multiple objects like a cupboard, table, fan etc.

How can I display all of the objects together, so that they remain at same place, on all screen resolutions?

Comment: Are you looking to make a 2D (side scroller or topdown), 3D, or isometric game?

Comment: The same place relative to what? The left/top edge of the screen?

Comment: What technology are you using? Are you using a simple canvas element for drawing? Because canvas elements have set attributes for determining their size and resolution, so they'll appear the same size on all platforms. However, a common mistake is to set the size through CSS, which only stretches the canvas without changing the resolution.

Comment: @eskimo it is a 2D game

Comment: @totov Sample place relative to container, it could be the whole body or a div with predefined area

Comment: @awsumpwner27 I'm using just HTML5 and Javascript

Comment: For now I've not even gone with Canvas. I've put everything in a fixed area and positioned objects relative to that area..